# Is there a way of adding lockable resources permissions to a Jenkins Role via a groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to configure Jenkins Global Roles (Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin) via a groovy script that can be executed via https://jenkins-url/script or from the jenkins init directory on startup.

I've been able to set all the permissions I need for the role with the exception of two:

- Lockable Resources/Reserve
- Lockable Resources/Unlock

I have been unable to find what params I need to add in my groovy code for these two role permissions. I've been able to apply them in the past using config as code but now I want to do it in groovy.

How is one expected to look these values up?
I've lucked out for the other permissions by finding other online examples.
E.g.

```
adminPermissions.add(Permission.fromId("hudson.model.Run.Delete"));
adminPermissions.add(Permission.fromId("hudson.model.Hudson.UploadPlugins"));
```

I've tried looking for examples online with no luck for this particular permission. I've also taken a look at the plugin source on [github lockable resources plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/lockable-resources-plugin) with no luck.

```
import hudson.*
import hudson.security.*
import jenkins.model.*
import java.util.*
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.*
import com.synopsys.arc.jenkins.plugins.rolestrategy.*
import java.lang.reflect.*
import java.util.logging.*
import groovy.json.*

import jenkins.*
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.*

// Turn security on
def roleBasedAuthenticationStrategy = new RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy()
Jenkins.instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(roleBasedAuthenticationStrategy)

Constructor[] constrs = Role.class.getConstructors();
for (Constructor<?> c : constrs) {
  c.setAccessible(true);
}

Method assignRoleMethod = RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.class.getDeclaredMethod("assignRole", String.class, Role.class, String.class);
assignRoleMethod.setAccessible(true);
Set<Permission> adminPermissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
adminPermissions.add(Permission.fromId("<what goes here?>"));
Role adminRole = new Role("admin", adminPermissions);
roleBasedAuthenticationStrategy.addRole(RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.GLOBAL, adminRole);

Jenkins.instance.save()
```

Expected results: Permissions are ticked in the Global Roles section of the Jenkins UI.
Actual results: unchecked permissions as shown below

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 'org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.Unlock'
- 'org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.Reserve
  '

this is available from:

```
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("")
  Permission.getAll().each { p ->
    logger.info(p.getId())
  }
```